# what does curly braces mean in web.config file?

Tags: variables, web-config, setting

In my project, connection string is like the following :

> connectionString="Server=localhost; Database={DatabaseName}; User Id=sa; password=sa"

What does {DatabaseName} mean?
If I want to change the DatabaseName to some other database name, where should I make the change?

Comment: What sort of project? Looks like you could just hardcode it in right there... but I have no idea what framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly braces and put in your database name.

For example:

```
     <add key="ConnectionString" value="server=localhost;database=Northwind;uid=sa;password=admin;" />
```